# I am getting the error "Overflow." in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, numbers, integer, runtime-error, largenumber

```
Dim clicks As Integer
clicks = 0

If clicks >= 10000000000000000000 Then
    a19.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 153, 0)
End If
```

10000000000000000000 and above gives the error.
Is there any way to have unlimited large length numbers?

Comment: Is there any sepcific reason you need to use such large numbers? It doesn't really make sense in this context. (clicking)

Comment: With a rate of 100 clicks per second, the 10000000000000000000 clicks will be reached after 7.6 billion years - more than half of the age of the universe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Long instead of Integer to allow you to go up to about 9 * 10E18 (9 followed by 18 zeros). Use the L suffix on literals if they are Long

```
Dim bigNumber as Long = 5000000000000000000L
```

If you want integers that can be any size at all, look at the [BigInteger Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For example (the following requires a reference to the System.Numerics DLL as well as the statement `Imports System.Numerics`

```
    Dim clicks As BigInteger = 0

    'Code that updates click goes here

    Dim limit As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("10000000000000000000")
    If clicks >= limit Then
        a19.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 153, 0)
    End If
```

You can also use Double to hold number as large as 1E308, but it can't hold 308 decimal digits, so the numbers will only be approximations.

Comment: would using BigInteger be like: Dim clicks As New BigInteger or Dim clicks As BigInteger ?

Comment: It's a Structure, so `Dim clicks As BigInteger`. See the documentation I linked to. You will need to add a reference to System.Numerics.

Comment: So i i added this to it but there are parts underlines (errors) <SerializableAttribute> _
Public Structure BigInteger _
 Implements IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable(Of BigInteger),  _
 IEquatable(Of BigInteger)
End Structure

Comment: I updated my answer to include a version of your original code that uses BigInteger.

Comment: Imports System.Numerics is wrong as it is underlined green?

Comment: `Imports System.Numerics` is correct, but you must add a reference to the System.Numerics DLL. Double-click on "My Project" in Solution Explorer, and go to the "References" tab and click "Add". I should have added that BigInteger is only available in version 4 and later of the .Net Framework.

Comment: thanks for explaining that to me. I would have been stuck on the reference part. so now i can do Dim clicks As BigInteger = 0 ?

Comment: Yes. Give it a try and it should work. However (as other commenters have pointed out), if clicks is actually a count of user clicks, it is unlikely that you need numbers this big.

Comment: it still shows error Overflow after changing it from Integer to BigInteger

Comment: Dim clicks As BigInteger and clicks = 10000000000000000000

Comment: See the code in my answer `Dim limit As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("10000000000000000000")` there is no way to write a literal that is that big, so you need to use BigInteger.Parse to convert a string to a BigInteger.

Comment: ok cool. 1 more thing though. I am saving the value in the project settings using My.Settings. in there you can set the type to anything but is there a way to set the type to BigInteger as i have it at Integer now.

Comment: I don't believe you can store a BigInteger in MySettings, which means you will have to convert the BigInteger to something else before you save it. One possibility would be to convert it to a String using the `ToString` method of BigInteger. When you want to convert the String back to a BigInteger, you can use `BigInteger.Parse`.

Comment: Thanks i got it to work. `Dim clicks as BigInteger` and `My.Settings.clicks = clicks.ToString`

Answer (score 1):

In Computer Science a number is most often represented as an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)). An integer is most often defined as a *32-bit signed* integer, which means  that the value can only hold up to a value from -(2^31) to (2^31)-1. To use bigger numbers, you might want to check other integer types. The most commonly used bigger integer, is the *64-bit integer*, which can hold a value from -(2^63) to (2^63)-1.